# Django _unicode_(self) not working properly

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unicode, django-models

I am learning django using Python 2.7 and currently having trouble with *unicode* .*unicode*(self) function keeps returning SighnUp object instead of email.I have tried "return str(self.email)" .It still returns SignUP Objects whenever i save new signups.
Here is my code:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class SignUp(models.Model):
    email=models.EmailField()
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updates=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the method name, you need to use **two** underscores before and after:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.email
```

Note that you must return a `unicode` object, not a `str`. The `EmailField` value is a `unicode` object already, just return that unchanged.

Comment: Ahh,thanks a lot sir.Newbie mistake.